# Ubuntu distro always start in setup mode

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04, distro

We have our own distribution of Linux based on Ubuntu Server 18.04 with a lot of customizations. 
We have a .sh for generating the ISO. Everything works good.

What we want is that ISO to start always in 'setup mode' without the need to press Ctrl-Alt-F1 during the boot.

Right now, if we don't press that, Linux will launch normally right from the CD/USB. We want to prevent that situation.

How to achieve that? any configuration file?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: Declared off-topic in askubuntu as well. This is not a usability question. It is about how to configure a newly created distro correctly (some command for the shell script or config file) in order to start in 'setup mode' rather than as a Live CD.